# FreeIPA 4.6.4 on CentOS 7 returns blank page on Firefox due to CSP

Tags: centos7, firefox, freeipa

I have created a CentOS 7 droplet on DigitalOcean and installed and configured ipa-server 4.6.4 following DigitalOcean's [how-to](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-centralized-linux-authentication-with-freeipa-on-centos-7). Connecting from Firefox 67 gets a blank page; connecting from Chromium works. The developer console on Firefox 67 gives errors about Content Security Policy for "script-src"; searching the httpd config files and IPA pages on my droplet, the only CSP it applies is:

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/ipa.conf:  Header always append Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'none'"`

How do I fix either FreeIPA or Firefox for them to work together?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Firefox 67.0.4 on Fedora 30 and have no problems like that. W3C CSP spec recommends having default-src, so when I added it, nothing changed for me:

```
Header always append Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'"
```

Perhaps, there are some specific settings that should be activated in Firefox to enforce the handling of it but I didn't find any.

Correction: I tried to expand the policy a bit and stumbled upon an issue with CSP in dojo code. We are going to look into upgrading dojo in FreeIPA soon, then the policy will be improved.